# UICollectionView header dynamic height using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a `UICollectionView` with a header of type `UICollectionReusableView`.

In it, I have a label whose length varies by user input.

I'm looking for a way to have the header dynamically resize depending on the height of the label, as well as other subviews in the header.

This is my storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

This the result when I run the app:

[image: result]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873537/how-to-dynamically-add-labels-and-buttons-in-section-header-of-uicollectionview

Comment: probably, the question is duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642493/dynamic-uicollectionview-header-size-based-on-uilabel

Comment: @Ahmad the first solution not working with me, the second I don't know how I create a nib of header to try it, if you have any idea about it please I need your help

Answer (score 80):

Here's an elegant, up to date solution.

As stated by others, first make sure that all you have constraints running from the very top of your header view to the top of the first subview, from the bottom of the first subview to the top of the second subview, etc, and from the bottom of the last subview to the bottom of your header view. Only then auto layout can know how to resize your view.

The following code snipped returns the calculated size of your header view.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    // Get the view for the first header
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)
    let headerView = self.collectionView(collectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath)

    // Use this view to calculate the optimal size based on the collection view's width
    return headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize.height),
                                              withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, // Width is fixed
                                              verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel) // Height can be as large as needed
}
```

### Edit

As @Caio noticed in the comments, this solution will cause a crash on iOS 10 and older.
In my project, I've "solved" this by wrapping the code above in `if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { ... }` and providing a fixed size in the else clause. That's not ideal, but acceptable in my case.

Comment: best answer, but note that the collectionView.frame.width for systemLayoutSizeFitting may be smaller due to insets and margins... you can be more precise by using: let bounds = collectionView.bounds
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let width = bounds.size.width - layout.sectionInset.left - layout.sectionInset.right - layoutMargins.left - layoutMargins.right

Comment: Your solution makes my cell resize correctly, however I get a huge amount of NSLayoutUnsatisfiableConstraint errors. The same cell is used as a "normal" content cell in another collection view, and there, it resizes correctly. I've used this tutorial to implement the dynamic cell resizing: https://medium.com/@andrea.toso/uicollectionviewcell-dynamic-height-swift-b099b28ddd23

Again, it works for the regular cells in another collection view, but not in this one, if I'm using it as a header cell.

Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: Please notice that it WONT WORK on iOS 9/10. Due to the fact that you can't dequeue a supplementary view BEFORE the `collectionView(collectionView:kind:at)` gets called by the delegate. It will crash.

Comment: doesn't work at all because this method is even not called

Comment: It seems this is the right way, however, there's an insidious bug in the method call: `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`

Its implementation calls `dequeueReusableSupplementaryView()` which leads to creating another instance of the headerView. Since `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` is called quite often there's a lot of headerViews will be created and moreover there will be visual bugs if the flow layout is used with `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds` set to `true`. 

As a solution, the header view can be a lazy property instead: `lazy var headerViewToMeasureHeight: UIView = { ... }()`

Comment: it doesn't work for me, as view aren't created at reference method call, datasource method called later

Answer (score 36):

This drove me absolutely crazy for about half a day.
Here's what finally worked.

Make sure the labels in your header are set to be dynamically sizing, one line and wrapping

1. Embed your labels in a view. This will help with autosizing.
   [image]
2. Make sure the constraints on your labels are finite. ex: A greater-than constraint from the bottom label to the reusable view will not work. See image above.
3. Add an outlet to your subclass for the view you embedded your labels in

   ```
   class CustomHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
       @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
   }
   ```
4. Invalidate the initial layout

   ```
   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

       collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
   }
   ```
5. Lay out the header to get the right size

   ```
   extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

           if let headerView = collectionView.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader).first as? CustomHeader {
               // Layout to get the right dimensions
               headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

               // Automagically get the right height
               let height = headerView.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize).height

               // return the correct size
               return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: height)
           }

           // You need this because this delegate method will run at least 
           // once before the header is available for sizing. 
           // Returning zero will stop the delegate from trying to get a supplementary view
           return CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Realized this won't necessarily work with longer lists since the header won't be visible when returning to that list. For a shorter list this will still work.

Comment: I made this work by having a reference to header view in controller. Than you!

Comment: It's a solution, but there is a warning for UICollectionView, either dequeueReusableSupplementaryView or dequeueReusableCell to calculate the SupplementaryView/Cell's size will get that warning.

Comment: To make this work for me, with longer lists that make the header not visible when scrolling I had to store the header as a class attribute (at the time of dequeueing), then inside the above method did: if let header = self.header.

Comment: this method called before headers created

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
    return CGSize(width: self.myCollectionView.bounds.width, height: self.mylabel.bounds.height)
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617702-collectionview

Comment: how is this an answer? what is a self.mylabel in here? any explanation?

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve it by implementing the following:

The ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    // the text that you want to add it to the headerView's label:
    fileprivate let myText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind,
                                                                             withReuseIdentifier: "customHeader",
                                                                             for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionReusableView

            headerView.lblTitle.text = myText
            headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            return headerView
        default:
            fatalError("This should never happen!!")
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        // ...

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        // ofSize should be the same size of the headerView's label size:
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: myText.heightWithConstrainedWidth(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)))
    }
}


extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

The custom `UICollectionReusableView`:

```
class CustomCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // setup "lblTitle":
        lblTitle.numberOfLines = 0
        lblTitle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        lblTitle.sizeToFit() 
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not using dynamic height and autolayout.

Answer (score 3):

@Pim's answer worked for me but as @linus_hologram in the comment section mentioned  this solution makes AutoLayout complain about unsatisfiable constraints. I found a simple workaround:

In `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)` instead of getting a reference to the view that your instance of `UICollectionView` wants to reuse using `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:)` just create an instance of your header view class on the fly and add a width constraint so that `AutoLayout` will be able to calculate your header's width:

```swift
let headerView = YourCustomHeaderClass() 
headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: collectionView.frame.width).isActive = true
return headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to dynamically layout multiple supplementary headers with different heights, using `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is painful.

Instead I suggest using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` with the `.estimated()` height dimension. After stuck in flow layout for a morning, compositional layout works like a charm:

```
lazy var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { [weak self] (sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

        // define items, group and section
        // (I'll skip some code since it's not relevant to the question)
        let itemSize = ...
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(...)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(...)
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)

        // define header
        // * the magic is here: use .estimated() to dynamically set height for header
        let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(72))
        let header = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .topLeading)
        section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [header]

        return section
    }

    return layout
}()
```

Of course you need to set the layout in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout
}
```