# Auto size view on tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am having a view at the top of my tableViewController.
 The view is called `viewBackground`. 
It is there to show the post the user clicked on and the table cells will show the comments.

What I want to do is to resize the `viewBackground` depending on the size of the label `theLabel`.
 I have done this in the cells by setting the label in the cells to 0 lines and by implementing this little code :

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 205
```

How do I do the same with my `viewBackground`?

This is a picture of the tableView:

[image]

Comment: Show me your tableview screen UI

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya it is added.

Comment: i cant catch your question .please make some clarification about what you actually want

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make a header for your current tableView -instead of adding an external view above it-, and then you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825290/make-uicollectionview-header-dynamic-height/39832379#39832379), it should helps you of how you can calculate the label's string height and returning it in the [tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview) method.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I think I am making a header, by adding the view?

Comment: yes, make it simpler by adding a new cell to your tableView and implement [viewForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) method. Please check the url in the answer, it should help you to calculate the height of the label, but instead of referenceSizeForHeaderInSection, it should be only the height ([heightForHeaderInsSection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview))

Comment: anyway, if you couldn't understand it at all, just make sure that using  [viewForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) is fit for your case and shoot a comment, I'll be glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create table view with two sections. First section will contain selected post; second section - comments. If you need, i can provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Added this code and it helped!

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame

        //Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```